# Difference between "on top of" and "over"

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

**[This question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/70250/whats-the-word-for-roads-on-top-of-roads)** used the phrase **on top of** to describe an overpass over another road. When one of the answers suggested that "over" would be more appropriate because there is space between the bridge and the road, the questioner disagreed. But I can not think of any situation where I would use **on top of** when there is no direct contact between surfaces (Northeast US English).

For example:

> "The bird is on top of the building," means the bird is perched on the
>   building itself.
>
> "The bird is over the building," means the bird is in
>   the air over the building.

Can **on top of** be used when there is no direct contact between the things below and above? Does this vary regionally?

Comment: The difference is also in that "on top" is the location while "over" **can** mean direction.

Comment: An interesting photo: [Plane Is Flying On Top Of The Building At Las Vegas , Nevada , USA](http://www.panoramio.com/photo/16012158). :-)

Comment: Should they change the name to ontopofpass?

Comment: Some Dictionaries state that on top of something also means on or over something . I think when something is over another thing and near to it, we can use on top of.

Comment: To this native speaker of American English, "on top of X" almost always means "in direct contact with X" whereas "over X" means "located higher than X".  "The cow jumped *over* the moon", it did not jump on top of the moon.  I am "*on top* of Old Smoky" mountain, not over Old Smoky.

Answer (score 1):

"The bird is over the building,"

I would rather say "The bird is *above* the building" instead of that.

Meanwhile:

*On top of* talks about position,

*Over* is direction.

Answer (score 0):

There are idiomatic phrases used to indicate interaction but not necessarily having physical contact: For example, *I'm on top of it*, meaning the speaker is indicating involvement in some work assignment; and *I'm on top of the world*, meaning the speaker is happy/elated about something.

Comment: More frequently I've heard it without "*top of*" at all: "I'm **on it**"...

Comment: And "I'm on top of it" would be completely different from "I'm over it" of course.

Answer (score 0):

**"on top of"** is informal because it includes prepositions.
**Over** is formal and academic. So, they have the same meaning. For example; The bridge is on top of the road, or the bridge is over the road.